# A cmake option that automatically specifies new values for other cmake options

Tags: cmake, build

Currently my `CMakeLists.txt` file contains lots of little options for including or excluding particular pieces of functionality from the build; by default everything is built, but the user remove a feature from the build by passing an argument like `-DWITH_FEATURE_X=OFF` on the command line:

```
option(WITH_FEATURE_X "Enable feature X" ON)
if (WITH_FEATURE_X)
   file(GLOB FEATURE_X_SRCS "${TOP_DIR}/feature_x/*.cpp")
   list(APPEND ALL_SRCS ${FEATURE_X_SRCS})
else ()
   message("CMake:  -DWITH_FEATURE_X=OFF argument was specified:  building without feature X.")
   add_definitions(-DAVOID_FEATURE_X)
endif ()
```

... this works fine, but it's a little tedious in some cases where the caller has to specify a dozen `-DWITH_FEATURE_X=OFF` type arguments on the command line.

Since I know in advance of several common uses-cases where the user would like to specify a known set of features to be disabled, I'd like to be able to specify that with a single argument, something like this:

```
cmake -DWITH_MINIMAL_CONFIGURATION=ON ..
```

.... and have the CMakeLists.file act as if the user had specified:

```
cmake -DWITH_FEATURE_X=OFF -DWITH_FEATURE_Y=OFF -DWITH_FEATURE_Z=OFF [...and so on...] ..
```

Is there a way to do that, that won't overcomplicate the implementation of the `CMakeLists.txt` file?

Comment: I would use CMake presets for this. So a `minimal_configuration` preset would set all those variables. You can build a tree of configuration presets (e.g. Windows/Unix, Debug/Release pending of Windows/Linux, MinimalDebug pending of WindowsDebug, and so on) and then have a set of build presets use some of those configuration presets. I have an example [here](https://github.com/rturrado/the_modern_cpp_challenge).

Comment: Upvoted the presets comment. But just mentioning that I personally on older cmake versions used to encounter such wrappers of options written in shell or python that then simply calls cmake. Ie you can have a “profile” in the wrapper that then calls cmake with all the individual options correctly set.

Comment: CMakePresets is probably the cleanest solution. You can also create a separate `.cmake` file where you define `IF(WITH_MINIMAL_CONFIGURATION)` and set individual variables and include the file at the end. However if I'm not mistaken the CMakePresets gets picked up by IDEs and is thus more user-friendly.

Comment: Thanks @rturrado that is just what I needed; I have it working using a cmake presets file now.  If you want to make your comment into an answer I will mark it.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I'm glad it helped. I've added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CMake presets](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html) (since version 3.19) could be a good option here.

You could have a `minimal_configuration` configuration preset that would set those variables as `cacheVariables`. And then a `minimal_configuration` build preset that would use the `minimal_configuration` configuration preset.

```
  "configurePresets": [
    {
      "name": "minimal_configuration",
      ...
      "cacheVariables": {
        "WITH_FEATURE_X": "OFF",
        "WITH_FEATURE_Y": "OFF",
        "WITH_FEATURE_Z": "OFF",
        ...
      },
    }
  ],
  "buildPresets": [
    {
      "name": "minimal_configuration",
      "configurePreset": "minimal_configuration"
    }
  ]
```

Notice you can define a hierarchy of configuration presets, and let each level of that hierarchy manage different settings. For example, you could have a `common_config` first level, a `windows_config` and `unixlike_config` second level, a `windows_debug_config`, `windows_release_config` (and so on) third level...

In order to run CMake for a given preset, just pass it as a command line option:

```
~/your_project> cmake --preset minimal_configuration
~/your_project> cmake --build --preset minimal_configuration
```